# Finding minimal number in array

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to write a program which finds the minimal number of 5 inputted numbers. I'm stuck at the point when I want to use function getMinNum, but there is an error saying: expected expression before ']' token
I understand it has a connection with pointers, however I would like to do it without them if it is possible of course.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float getMinNum(float a[], int x);
int main() 
{
    int n = 5;
    int i;
    float z[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%f", &z[i]);
    }

    printf("%6.2f", getMinNum(z[], n));
    return 0;
}

float getMinNum(float a[], int x)
{
    int i, min = a[0];
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        if(min > a[i+1]){
            min = a[i+1];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can start the loop in `getMinNum()` with `i = 1`; you know that `a[0]` is the same value as what's in `min`...well, if `min` was a `float` and not an `int`, you would.  You should check that the `fscanf()` calls all succeed before using the data.  You're also using a VLA (variable length array).  No harm done, but you should be aware that you're doing so.

Comment: Specifically, you should be aware that you're using a variable length array because the compiler may allow you to set n = 0.  This would lead to out-of-range memory access using @ed-heal's solution, which assumes `a[0]` is a valid member.  If you declare `z` with `float z[5]`, the compiler will enforce that assumption.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't append '[]' to the variable name.

Instead of:

```
printf("%6.2f", getMinNum(z[], n));
```

do:

```
printf("%6.2f", getMinNum(z, n));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `a[i+1]` will be using values outside the array, so use `a[i]` instead.

So the code should look like

```
float getMinNum(float a[], int x){

    int i;
    float min = a[0]; // Min needs to be a float
    for(i=1; i<x; i++){ // Do not need to check a[0]

        if(min > a[i]){
            min = a[i];
        }

    }

    return min;
}
```

And call it as

```
printf("%6.2f", getMinNum(z, n));
```